# In the Clang AST how to know if a DeclRefExpr in a method refers to a local or a non-static data member of the struct/class containing the method?

Tags: c++, clang

In the Clang AST how to know if a DeclRefExpr in a method refers to a local or a non-static data member of the struct/class containing the method?

That is, if I were translating the C++ to C and I were explicitly inserting the 'this' parameter and I wanted to explicitly prefix all references to the members of the 'this' class by translating 'x' into 'this->x', how do I know for which DeclRefExprs to do this?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that we want to call NamedDecl::isCXXInstanceMember() on the output of DeclRefExpr::getDecl()

but the context in which I wanted to know this makes it moot: Clang seems to insert explicit MemberExpr and CXXThisExpr expressions when a non-static data member is accessed